# node call back - code not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

This is my code in a node - express  to send out an email once the sql transaction is done successfully !

```
router.post('/',function(req,res,next){
    sql.connect(config).then(function() {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query(`update projects set CIP_NCIP= '${req.body.cip_noncip}' , Capital_Expense ='${req.body.capital_expensed}' , Approval_Status ='Approved' where Project_ID ='${req.body.projid}'`).then(function(recordset) {
            console.log('Recordset: ' + recordset);
            console.log('Affected: ' + request.rowsAffected);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('Request error: ' + err);
            }
        })
    }).then(
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            }
        })).catch(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('SQL Connection Error: ' + err);
        }

    });
});
```

the sql insert seems to work but its not executing this bit of code

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
                }
            })
```

fairly new to callbacks and es5 . suggestions welcome

Comment: Couple of issues I can see but as far as code executing, it looks likt it should work - if you move the `sendMail` call into the callback of `request.query` does it work ok in there? Also where does `mailOptions` come from? Don't see that in the code, are we to assume that this exists and is configured correctly?

Comment: this is the entire js file  https://www.itextpad.com/nXB8DStC2s

Comment: even a console.log('test') inside of the callback of the request.query does not work whch is quite confusing.

Comment: try the code I've suggested, it should help you narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your current code, your not actually doing things in the correct order (which may or may not be the issue). Try this:

```
var request = sql.Request();
sql.connect(config)
    .then(function() {
        console.log('UPDATING RECORD...');
        return request.query(`update projects set CIP_NCIP= '${req.body.cip_noncip}' , Capital_Expense ='${req.body.capital_expensed}' , Approval_Status ='Approved' where Project_ID ='${req.body.projid}'`);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`SQL Connection Error: ${err}`);
        }
    })
    .then(function(recordset) {
        console.log('Recordset: ' + recordset);
        console.log('Affected: ' + request.rowsAffected);
        console.log('SENDING EMAIL...');
        return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`Nodemailer Err: ${err}`);
        }
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log('COMPLETE');
    });        
    console.log('CONNECTING...');
```

The above is leveraging Promises to the fullest extent and includes some logging that should help you narrow down where the issue is.

FWIW here's how it would look in ES6 (without the debug logging)

```
sql.connect(config)
   .then(() => sql.Request().query('...'))
   .catch(err => console.error(`SQL Error ${err}`))
   .then(() => transporter.sendMail(mailOptions))
   .catch(err => console.error(`Nodemailer err: ${err}`);
```

Comment: @SSS cool, you should consider updating to ES6, your code would be a lot more succinct (I updated my answer with an example).

Comment: may be i should . any interesting tutorials you would recommend?

Answer (score 2):

A promise follows the promise chain by executing the functions you provide attached via `.then` method.

In your case you have :

```
sql.connect( config )
   .then( function() { ... } )
   .then( valueNotAFunction );
```

If the return value of the function executed by `then` is a promise itself, then the next block will wait for finishing the previous one.

The code block :

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
     if (error) {
         console.log(error);
     } else {
         console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
     }
}))
```

is executed immediately, not after the previous function in the chain has finished.

Also the `request.query` evaluates to Promise, which you don't return back to the chain.

Your code should look like :

```
sql.connect( config )
   .then( function() { .... ; return request.query( ... ) } )
   .then( function() { .... ; return transporter.sendMail(....) } )
   .catch( function( error ) { console.error( error ); } );
```

Keep in mind that `transporter.sendMail` might not evaluate to Promise and so you might want to wrap it with [some promisification library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html).

Comment: So I also noticed this, however it doesn't explain why the code wouldn't run. If anything, it would simply mean the email would fire before the DB update.

Comment: Most probably the `transporter.sendMail` is having it's connection being initialized and that's why is not sending the mail immediately. There is no way to guess what's happening there, without knowing what is `transporter.sendMail` doing.

Comment: based on the code, my guess is the OP is using [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) which _can_ return a Promise. However, I notice the OP is providing a callback so won't in their case.

Comment: if i place the trasporter.sendMail outside of this code block it seems to fire and email . so its not a problem with the transporter.sendmail

Comment: @James yes i am using nodemailer

Comment: no no other error ... only  Recordset: undefined
Affected: 1

Answer (score 0):

looks like you forget to return promise as-

```
return request.query(`update projects set CIP_NCIP= '${req.body.cip_noncip}' , Capital_Expense ='${req.body.capital_expensed}' , Approval_Status ='Approved' where Project_ID ='${req.body.projid}'`).then(function(recordset) {
            console.log('Recordset: ' + recordset);
            console.log('Affected: ' + request.rowsAffected);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('Request error: ' + err);
            }
        })
```

Comment: You don't _have_ return return promises to chain.